# Changing drag & drop behaviour in Windows 7's explorer for touch screen use

Tags: windows-7, touchscreen, drag-and-drop

I have a new touch screen, and am playing around with its functionality. The most productive use for me is organizing files (literally) by hand. It's fun working through a list of files, dragging and dropping them to the right locations using your index finger. It feels better on the wrist than mouse-clicking, too.

The only problem is that when I drag & drop files across drives in Windows 7, the default behaviour is to *copy* the file instead of moving it. I know I can influence this using right click, but that is of course no option in my situation.

How can I change the default drag & drop behaviour in Windows 7's explorer?

> Starting a bounty to see whether there is anything new.

Comment: Are you not able to tap-hold with your finger, and then drag-drop for the context menu? This works like right-click-dragging in Windows 10,

Answer (score 4):

**This is possible**.  Let's ask ourselves two questions:

- **What hapens when we drag and drop a file?**

  - An API function is called to start dragging the file.
  - A window is shown while you drag.
  - An API function is called when you drop the file.
  - The operation is performed.
- **How can we modify the drag-drop behavior?**

  - We could hook the API function(s) and adjust the parameters/code to move instead of copy.
  - *But, there is an easier way*: We could use a hotkey modifier while dragging...

So, by some simple scripting, we can **hold the SHIFT key** when you drop the file based on the window!

After some research to figure out the name of the window (hook Window Title functions with [API Monitor](http://www.rohitab.com/apimonitor)) we can now create an [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) script that will hold the SHIFT key **until after you drop the file**.

```
LButton Down:: 
　  Send, {LButton Down}  
　  IfWinExist, ahk_class SysDragImage 
　  {
        Send, {LShift Down}
　  } 
　  return 

LButton Up::
    IfWinExist, ahk_class SysDragImage 
　  {
        Send, {LButton Up}
        Sleep, 500 ; Feel free to adjust higher/lower to improve the behavior.
        Send, {LShift Up}
　  } 
    Send, {LButton Up}
    return
```

Haven't really tried the above code, but I think I believe it should work.

Possible improvements:

- Use [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) instead with a function like [WinWait](http://www.autoitscript.com/wiki/WinWait), so you don't have to react on the mouse.
- Go for the hard stuff and write and hook the API functions, although you might need to hack a bit.

I hope the above script works or that I gave you a good start. :-)

Comment: Mmmmm, very interesting! I will definitely be testing this and giving feedback.

Comment: I won't be able to test this before the bounty runs out, but I'm awarding the bounty to you because this looks the most promising.

Answer (score 2):

Drag the file across and just before you're about to take your finger off the screen to copy, tap somewhere else on the screen at the same time.

> If you have a computer with a touchscreen, you might find that gestures (motions that you make with one or two fingers) are easier to use than a mouse, pen, or keyboard.

See **[Using touch gestures](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/Using-touch-gestures)** for more information.

> **Press and tap** (for touch screens with multiple touch points)
>
> Press the item with one finger, then quickly tap with another finger, while continuing to press the item with the first finger.
>
> Use press and tap to access the shortcut menu. Press and tap does the same thing as press and hold or right-clicking an item.

> **Press and hold** (for touch screens with a single touch point)
>
> Press and hold does the same thing as right-clicking an item. To perform the action, touch the screen where you want to right-click, hold until a complete circle appears, and then lift your finger. The shortcut menu appears after you lift your finger.

*... I guess you could perform this action to cut the file and then the same action to paste it into the destination folder if your touch screen only has a single touch point.*

Lots of other tricks on the webpage too, including panning, zoom and rotation.

Comment: Will try this too.

Comment: Sorry if this is a stupid answer and completely irrelevant.  From what I thought I read on Microsoft's website touch gestures are built in and will let you do right-clicking and all sorts of other clever stuff on a touchscreen.  Been a long day... sigh.

Comment: Ah, this indeed doesn't seem to apply, because pressing and tapping is not possible during a drag & drop operation.

Answer (score 1):

I have searched a bit and for what I can tell, it's not possible.

Comment: Cheers. I will post here if I happen to find anything.

Answer (score 0):

In the world of the mouse you can right click drag objects to gain access to more options regarding the operation.

[image]

You can invoke such a 'right click drag' from the touch screen interface. In the world of touch screens, a 'long' tap invokes context menus. To create a right-click-drag, just hold onto an object then drag it once the circle appears.

The only downside is that it will take longer.

Comment: Thanks jay. Using the finger, this won't work, because I have to release the finger for a moment (thus dropping the item) to invoke the long right click. Plus, it makes the organizing process too long.

Comment: @Pekka, updated answer. Right click drag is possible, but you're right that it will take longer. If you could somehow introduce a keyboard modifier key such as Shift (move), Ctrl (copy), Alt (shortcut) then it would be easier.