# Make Windows always copy files when dragging and dropping them

Tags: windows-7, drag-and-drop

Is there a way to change the default drag and drop behavior in Windows 7?

As of now it seems that if the location is on the same drive it'll move onto the other, otherwise if they are in different drives it'll copy.

Is there a way to change the setting so it'll always copy it?

Comment: In case you're interested Raymond Chen does explain the rational for why there's no setting for this in [Why can't the default drag/drop behavior be changed?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/06/09/427240.aspx)

Answer (score 13):

You could try the solution suggested in this answer: https://superuser.com/a/248961/71432

Alternatively, if you're not into coding, you can alter the behavior of drag-and-drop by manually holding down one of the modifier keys while dropping:

- Hold down the `Control` key to always copy.
- Hold down the `Shift` key to always move.
- Hold down the `Alt` key to always make a shortcut.

Comment: And in case of confusion with using these modifier keys: the drag cursor shows which action will be performed.

Answer (score 13):

If you have trouble or do not like remembering the key combinations [Amazed suggested](https://superuser.com/a/381588/82421) to use, then drag and drop with the *right mouse button* and you will be presented a nice window with these same options: copy, move, shortcut and cancel.

Comment: I've developed this habit a long time ago myself.

Answer (score 1):

There is a RegKey for this:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AllFileSystemObject\DefaultDropEffect
```

Keep in mind that although all other keys in AllFilesystemObjects are REG_SZ this one has to be a DWORD. The value for "always copy" would be 1 for "always move" it would be 2, and "create shortcut" 4. In this case decimal or hexadecimal does not make a difference as it is the same anyways.

The change will take effect without reboot, so you can immediately test it.

There is also a tool that does this called "[Drag'n'Drop Editor](http://winaero.com/comment.php?comment.news.69)" whichs features later were taken over to WinAero Tweaker.

Comment: Is there a registry key setting that allows control of specific directories instead of all file system objects?